# how to access a secure area passing username and password

Tags: php, http

I want to access this page which returns an xml file after entering the correct username and password
http://webservices.ns.nl/ns-api-avt?station=ut
I want to pass this xml to flash but I don't know how to pass the username and password
I am looking forward to something like that
username:password@webservices.ns.nl/ns-api-avt?station=ut
or using php
here the site url of that api if it helps http://www.ns.nl/api/api

thanks in advance

Comment: What's the point of a username / password if it's in plaintext?

Comment: it's for a client. I don't know the point and I can't change that. It returns xml file after I enter the username&pass thanks for your interest.

Comment: the xml might be updated as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in several ways in php..

if you happen to host your code in a linux env or has a native curl support, you can

```
$call = "curl --basic --user {$username}:{$password} \"{$url}\"";
exec($call, $resp);
print_r($resp);
```

or you can use the module `class.http.php` from [HTTP Library](https://web.archive.org/web/20120702153036/http://www.phpfour.com:80/lib/http/)

```
$http = new Http();
$http->useCurl(false);
$http->setMethod($method);
$http->setAuth($user, $pass);
$http->execute($url);
$resp = $http->error ? $http->error : $http->result;
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP exemple with curl on php.net: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php#98164 
the interesting part is:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "username:password");
```